# Split 1 row into multiple rows of hourly data based on datetime column keeping one column values as sliding window in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataset that shows Actual vs Predicted values

| Start Time | End Time | Actual | Predicted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/1/2022 20:00 | 4/2/2022 22:00 | 0.749123 | [[0.41], [0.34]] |
| 4/1/2022 21:00 | 4/2/2022 23:00 | 0.770175 | [[0.32], [0.28]] |

I want to split this up into different hours such that one row only contains one hour of data and Actual column should not repeat itself and should follow rolling window of two values at a time.

This is the data frame that I want to get.

| Start Time | End Time | Actual | Predicted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4/1/2022 20:00 | 4/2/2022 21:00 | 0.749123 | 0.41 |
| 4/1/2022 21:00 | 4/2/2022 22:00 | 0.770175 | 0.34 |
| 4/1/2022 21:00 | 4/2/2022 22:00 | 0.749123 | 0.32 |
| 4/1/2022 22:00 | 4/2/2022 23:00 | 0.770175 | 0.28 |

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what exactly you want the result to look like but the pandas [.explode()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) method should definetly be helpful.

Comment: Thanks.When i am using explode in Actual column i am getting duplicates that i don't want.